# How do I update a json column with a subquery?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have MySQL 5.7 and table1 with json column data.

```
SELECT id, data 
FROM table1;
```

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5'} |

I can use:

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`t1`.`data`, JSON_OBJECT('key1', 'value1', 'key2', 'value2'));
```

I will get:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} |

How can I get data from a subquery and make `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` with that?

From table2:

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'key10' | 'value10' |
| 2 | 'key13' | 'value13' |
| 3 | 'key100' | 'value100' |

I tried to use

```
SELECT key, value FROM table2
```

with `JSON_ARRAY` etc into `JSON_MERGE_PATCH`, but it is not correct.

Subquery returns rows from the table2 in the "key, value"-structure.

Expected data:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'key3': 'value3', 'key10': 'value10', 'key13': 'value13', 'key100': 'value100'} |
| 2 | {'key5': 'value5', 'key10': 'value10', 'key13': 'value13', 'key100': 'value100'} |

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I have added a expected data in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

Edit: I misspelled JSON_OBJECTAGG() as JSON_OBJECT_AGG() in my previous answer. I have fixed it as JSON_OBJECTAGG():

```
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`t1`.`data`, 
    (SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(`key`, value) FROM table2));
```

Tested in MySQL 5.7.34. Note you must delimit the column name `key` in back-ticks because it's a reserved keyword.

Result after running the update:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | data                                                                             |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"key3": "value3", "key10": "value10", "key13": "value13", "key100": "value100"} |
|  2 | {"key5": "value5", "key10": "value10", "key13": "value13", "key100": "value100"} |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg for details on the `JSON_OBJECT_AGG()` function.

Comment: JSON_OBJECTAGG() was added in MySQL 5.7.22. Are you using Amazon Aurora? They forked from MySQL 5.7 before JSON_OBJECTAGG() was added.

Comment: It's close, yes, thanks.

Correct way is  to use with GROUP BY and JSON_OBJECTAGG()
UPDATE `table1` as `t1`
SET `t1`.`data` =  JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`t1`.`data`, (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(`key`, `value`) FROM `table2` GROUP BY `id`));

Comment: In my real case I have more columns and I had some rows after  SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG. It has fixed by GROUP_BY or WHERE. Thanks a lot